# How to create a random action on Scratch

Tags: mit-scratch

I want to build a game with these actions:

1- Random jams are being shot at the wizard.
2- The player should hit the jam with his wand to break them before they touch the wizard.
3- If any jam touches the wizard, the game is over and it a big text is displayed.

I wrote this script for jam, the first problem is. When the game is over it hides, then when I restart the game it does not show.

2nd problem is, I don't know how to make a random number of jams and how to let them move randomly.

Here an image of the game:

[image: Jam Game]

Here's my script:

[image: Script]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPfZa.png)

Comment: Please explain why you tagged this question as `git`.

Comment: excuse me i didnt find scratch tag in site and must use one tag

Comment: Please give us the project link...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the script and explanation
[image]

- When the flag is clicked, a new jam is made every 1 second.
- The jam is spawned at the far right
- The clone will keep going left until it hits the edge, wizard or wand

  - After that it'll delete itself
  - If it touches the wizard, it will broadcast a game over state before deleting itself
- The Game Over state stops everything

**I hope this helped!**